# How do I indent footnotes?

Tags: footnotes, indentation

what is the easiest way to indent footnotes, right in the beginning? The way paragraphs are usually indented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load the package [footmisc](https://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) and set `\footnotemargin` to `\parindent` using `\setlength`:

```
\usepackage{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{\parindent}
```

Example (MWE) picture:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{\parindent}

\begin{document}

In fact, making reference to footnotes\footnote{reference to footnotes value
in a subsequent footnotemark or mpfootnotemark. This is a tedious way of going
about things} in general can be problematic: it can be done by noting down
the value of the footnote marker in a counter (or the like) and then using the
value in a subsequent footnotemark or mpfootnotemark. This is a tedious way of
going about things, and doesn't allow representation of all possible forms of
footnote mark; footref is a form of reference command
that sets the reference as if it were a footnote.

\end{document}
```